# How am I going wrong in answering this standard normal distribution question?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-walk, standard-deviation

Consider part (ii) of the below question:
[image: question]

Note: $p$ denotes the probability of an upward move of $1$. $q$ denotes the probability of a downward move of $1$.

Having looked as the solutions (which do not include workings), I know that the solution is $0.97831$.

Clearly, this is calculated using the standard normal distribution. I have attempted this as follows...

The expected value of the process after 1 move is 
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z_n] = (1 \cdot p) + (-1 \cdot q) = 0.45 - 0.55 = -0.1
$$
and the variance of the $Z_n$ variables is given by
$$
Var(Z_n) = 4pq = 0.99 = 0.995^2
$$
So, we have deduced that $Z_n ~ N(-0.1, 0.995^2)$ and thus $Y_{80} ~ N(-8, 0.995^2)$. Then, using the standard normal distribution, we have
$$
P(Y_{80} \leq 10) = P(z \leq \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}) \\
= P \left( z \leq \frac{10-(-8)}{0.995} \right) \\
= P(z \leq 18.091)
$$
This is clearly the point at which I have gone wrong, but I cannot see why. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** if $X\sim \mathcal{N}(m_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(m_y, \sigma_y^2)$ and they are independent, then $$X+Y \sim \mathcal{N}(m_x+m_y, \sigma_x^2+\sigma_y^2).$$

Comment: Ah, I see! My value for the standard deviation was incorrect. Thanks.